# AoO and subsequent rolls

Tags: pathfinder-1e, opportunity-attack

I read somewhere that if you take an action that causes an AoO, from the subsequent roll for that action, you have to subtract the eventually taken damage. Is it right?

If yes, does this apply too to the case where I move away from a threatened square, causing an AoO, to attack a creature? Do I have to subtract the damage from the AoO from my next attack roll?

I remember that I read this in the [System Operational Reference Digest](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2kxj5?SORD-PF-10-Released). There under Combat maneuvre (page 10) there is:

> Bull Rush (standard action)
>   One size category larger or less or part of a charge
>
> 1. Resolve AoO - Resolve AoO from the target. The Improved Bull Rush feat (or similar ability) avoids drawing AoO.
> 2. Roll - Subtract any target’s AoO damage on the roll.
> 3. Effect - Success: Push the target back 5 feet plus 5 more feet for each 5 by which the roll exceeds the CMD. You can move with the target if you have movement left.
>
> Fail: Your move ends in front of the target.
>   You cannot bull rush a target into a solid square or obstacle.

The point 2. says: *Subtract any target’s AoO damage on the roll.* This for all CM with a roll (disarm, grapple, overrun, etc).

Comment: Hardly worthy of an answer - but no, there is no such rule, at least not in 3.5.

Comment: The posted edits contain pathfinder specific rules. 3.5 does not use the same rules for combat maneuvers. Are you actually looking for 3.5 rules or just pathfinder?

Comment: @Francesco Glad you found an answer. However, instead of editing it into your question's text, please actually post your answer as an answer to your own question, and mark it as accepted! You can do that, and you should! In this case, you may want to accept _Colin D_'s answer since it already contains the CM answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If yes, does this apply too to the case where I move away from a
>   threatened square, causing an AoO, to attack a creature? Do I have to
>   subtract the damage from the AoO from my next attack roll?

In Pathfinder, it does apply to [combat maneuvers](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Combat-Maneuvers) which provoke an AoO, but not to movement provoking AoOs.

> Unless otherwise noted, performing a combat maneuver provokes an attack of opportunity from the target of the maneuver. If you are hit by the target, you take the damage normally and apply that amount as a penalty to the attack roll to perform the maneuver.

This rule only applies to combat maneuvers, not regular attacks.